# Probability question about a student passing maths and or english

Tags: probability

> The probability that a student passes mathematics is 2/3 and that he passes English is 4/9. If the probability of him passing both courses is ¼, what is the probability that the student will pass at least one of them?

I am really confused by this question, can someone shed some light?

What I thought is this:

$$(1-2/3) * (1-4/9) = 0.18518518518...$$

but what for would $1/4$ be in that case? I am confused.

Comment: Your thought of multiplying the probabilities is predicated on the two events being independent.  They are not, so you have to use (essentially) inclusion-exclusion to answer the question: $P(A \text{ or } B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \text{ and } B)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the significance of the $\frac14$ is that the outcomes are not independent. if they were the probability of passing both would be $\frac49 \times \frac 23 = \frac8{27} \gt \frac14$ suggesting a negative correlation between success in the two exams.

denote the probabilities of the different outcomes by $\{p_{e,m}\}$ where $e,m \in \{0,1\}$, with 1 indicating pass and 0 indicating fail in the subject corresponding to each index. then:

$$
p_{0,0} + p_{1,0} + p_{0,1} + p_{1,1} = 1 \\
p_{1,1} = \frac14 \\
p_{1,1} + p_{1,0} = \frac49 \\
p_{1,1} + p_{0,1} = \frac23
$$

Answer (score 2):

We know in probability that, for events $A,B$, where $A \cup B$ represents "$A$ or $B$" and $A \cap B$ represents "$A$ and $B$", we have

$$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$$

Let $A$ be the event in which the student passes math, and $B$ the event in which he passes English. Then

$$P(\text{passing one or both}) = P(\text{passing math}) + P(\text{passing English}) - P(\text{passing both})$$

Comment: but I thought that is the probability of exclusively one event happening? if that is not the case, what is the probability of just one event happening?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: what is the probability, that only A or only B passes? XOR, exclusive or

Comment: Still no clue what you're referring to. We're not trying to find the probability of finding exclusively passing math or English in the problem, we're looking for the probability of passing math, or passing English, or both (as the problem states, "what is the probability that the student will pass at least one of them?". This would correspond to finding $P(A \cup B)$. The rest of the variables are given in the problem: the probability of passing math, of passing English, and of passing both.

Comment: its a hypothetical question, what if the question was formulated in that only A or only B applies. I know that the question is not asking that. Or is the formula in that case complex?

Comment: @Toskan the probability that *exactly one* of the events occurs is $P(A)+P(B)-2P(A\cap B)$.